# Connect form at db conn?

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I am developing a CMS, but I'm stuck. For example, if I create a file with the following code db_conn.php:

```
private $host = "$field = $_POST['host_db'];"
private $user = "$field = $_POST['username_db'];"
private $password = "$field = $_POST ['db_password'];"
private $dbname = "$field = $_POST['name_db'];"
```

and then connect it to the various field
Can I do that?

Comment: I would suggest having a main config file and/or a setup script to configure things like this on install

Comment: You cant post to class variable directly submitting the form.

Comment: variable should not contain ' ' space $ host should $host